# Is <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"> mandatory when using the Open Graph Protocol?

Tags: html, meta, facebook-opengraph

Simple question:

Do I need this:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

To use this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Why?

Comment: If you don't add prefix it doesn't show up properly on LinkedIn as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042786/how-to-successfully-implement-ogimage-for-the-linkedin

Answer (score 0):

NO, it's not mandatory to use the tag.

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Instead. You can use:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="no" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Just like it was used in [nopiamanual.com](https://nopiamanual.com/) website.