# Share certificate URL with image on linkedin in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an elearning website in which I want to share the certificate of completion on Linkedin.

Currently, I'm using React-share but if I'm adding page url then image is not getting displayed whereas if image link is shared then post url is pointing to image link.

Certificate page url - https://learning.recruitingmonk.com/certificate/boolean-mastery?credID=RMK-bm-0006-GSY8-aaa

Please let me know some way to share my page url with preview image of certificate over linkedin in reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenGraph (`og` meta attributes) from Facebook.

Here is a QA answer from LinkedIn:

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a521928/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

The official documentation:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/?locale=en_US
- https://ogp.me/

And a related question StackOverflow question too:

[How to successfully implement og:image for the LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042786/how-to-successfully-implement-ogimage-for-the-linkedin)

Comment: I have used this method as well by adding og using React helmet but in that case the image remains static for all shares. And my problem here is if I'm sharing the image I'm not able to share the website page link. The normal image sharing is working perfectly.